# Google Sheets IF formula

Tags: google-sheets

Have a sheet where B column is "purchase date". C column is a drop down that can be "Weekly" or "Monthly". D column either 7 or 30 days from B column depending on what is selected in C. Basically, if "C" column is "Weekly" add 7 days to date entered in "B" column, but display it in "D" column. Would greatly appreciate any insight.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

`=arrayformula(if(C1:C2="Weekly",B1:B2+7,B1:B2+30))`

The cells need to be formatted as "Date".